# SQL query to find minimum difference between row values of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, difference, minimum

I am trying to find the minimum difference between years for each ID. For example,

I have this data:

```
ID     year
1      2001
1      2001
2      2003
2      2004
2      2010
3      2000
```

and I want this output:

```
ID    year
1      0
2      1
3      0
```

Comment: What did you try to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT Id,
       ISNULL(MIN(Def), 0) [Year]
FROM
(
  SELECT T.Id,
         TT.Year - T.Year Def
  FROM Data T
  LEFT JOIN Data TT ON T.Id = TT.Id AND T.Year < TT.Year
) T
GROUP BY Id;
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5c9dfc9f384307abe5c1454f96d98f7b)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select id, coalesce(min(year - prev_year), 0)
from (select t.*, lag(year) over (partition by id order by year) as prev_year
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=09677307bae32bcf40a1e16c27dd8ae8) is a db<>fiddle.